# .NET Core 2.1 API Post Controller returns invalid input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Authenticate")]
public ActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]LoginDTO Input)
{
    return Ok(Input);
}
```

LoginDTO is this

```
public class LoginDTO
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I use Postman to access it, I get this message

```
{
    "": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

How can I get my input? Should I not use objects? I tried getting it via String Username and String Password as parameters but it did not work as well.

EDIT:

Added Postman screenshot
[image]

Comment: Please post your view code too

Comment: I don't have a view. I'm using Postman

Comment: You have `[EmailAddress]` validation attribute, so you need to post the valid email address.

Comment: try to send valid email address to `Email` from postman and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw mode in Postman and send your request as Json

```
{"Email":"","Password":""}
```

Comment: This works. But why can't I use the ones that postman provides?

Comment: change your method like this :         public ActionResult Authenticate(LoginDTO Input)        and it will work,

Comment: When I remove the [FromBody] the same error happens. The input not valid one.

Comment: In header section of Postman, set Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I've done that. Same error. Not sure whats going on with this? If I create it using MVC5 it works okay.

Comment: What is your compatibility version?

Comment: Can you not compare the request from Postman when using raw mode and the non-raw mode using developer tools or fiddler and try and see what's different?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the method name in your URL

If your controller name Tokens then your URL should be like this

http://localhost:52309/api/Tokens/

then postman input should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you use PostMan you must select JSON(json.application) in raw mode

Comment: Future readers.  The default was "Text".  There is a drop down menu item to the right of "raw" in postman (my current version is postman 6.5.2).  Thanks Ali.